# Dependency injection in Controller's prototype

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to access dependencies in a controller's method without attaching it to the scope ?

```
Var myController = function($http, $window) {
 this.window = $window //this will slow the digest cicle 
}

myController.prototype.method = function() {

 // How do i access $http here ?

}

angular.module('app').controller('myController', myController)
```

Comment: What you are attempting here is highly irregular.  I'm curious to know why you want to do it like that?  Usually, you would make an Angular Service and use `$http` as a dependency of the service.

Comment: I've read few blog post advising to instantiate controllers like  'class', and i think it is more cleaner this way. it avoid having a 10k line function with all the methods in it

Comment: In these blog posts, does it show using the controller `prototype`?  Can you add a reference?

Comment: Why will adding the collaborators to the controller as properties slow the digest cycle? I think it will not.